# CreateML trace back images

Tags: ios, image, machine-learning, coreml, createml

I am concerned about the legal aspects of Apple's CreateML.

In some cases images with persons are needed and regarding to the new GDPR 2018 in the European Union, every person on an image must apporove the usage of it. This could lead to massive problems with picutres taken after the GDPR became active in May 2018.
Whats the best way to deal with this problem? Is it possible to trace back which images have been used to create a CoreML model with CreateML?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no about programming

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/how-will-the-gdpr-impact-machine-learning